# Pattern filter not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using date of birth pattern to check the date is correct filled. But it is not working, when I look for empty field it is working fine.

```js
function checkStatus() {
  var flag = false,
    name, date;
  var pattern = '/^([0-9]{1,2})\\/([0-9]{1,2})\\/([0-9]{4})$/';
  $('.name-field').each(function() {

    name = $(this).find('input[name="firstname[]"]').val();
    date = $(this).find('input[name="date[]"]').val();
    if (name == "" || date != pattern) {
      flag = true;
    }
  });
  return flag
}

//Toggle disbaled class
$('.name-field').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
  //use other static element or document if not works

  $('#stepname').toggleClass('disabled', checkStatus());
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name-field" class="name-field row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 childname">
    <div class="field text-left">
      <label class="text-left">Name</label>
      <input class="firstname" name="firstname[]" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 dateofbirth">
    <div class="field text-left">
      <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label>
      <input type="text" class="date" name="date[]" placeholder="DD / MM / JJJJ" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="stepname" class="btn disabled">Next step</a>
```

I hope you guys understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create a working snippet. Also expand on *But it is not working* to tell what isn't working and what is the expected output.

Comment: i want the date format DD/MM/YEAR, when it is correct filled in then remove the disabled class from the next step button that is not working, when i only look for the input field is not empty it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to be able to check test whether string matches the regular expression.

You can read more about RegExp test method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a callback function to a method, you just use the method name. Modify your code as follows:

`$('#stepname').toggleClass('disabled', checkStatus);`

Your pattern in date, is not working as you want. In order to match a regular expression, you need to use [any](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) js regular expression match:

```js
var re=/^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

let arr='12/12/1212'.match(re)

if( arr.length )
 console.log("Correct ", arr[0] )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your code will now look like this:

```js
function checkStatus() {
  var flag = true, 
      exp=[],
      name, 
      date,
      pattern = /^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;

  $('.name-field').each(function(i, e) {
     // i --> iterator index
     // e --> iteration item
     name = $(e).find('input[name="firstname[]"]').val();
     date = $(e).find('input[name="date[]"]').val();
     

     if(date)
        exp=date.match(pattern) 
     //console.log(name, date, exp);

     if (name == "" || !exp || exp.length == 0 ) {
       flag = false;
    }
  });
  return flag
}

//Toggle disbaled class
$('.name-field').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
  //use other static element or document if not works
  if(checkStatus())
      $('#stepname').removeClass('disabled');
  else if(!$('#stepname').hasClass('disabled'))
      $('#stepname').addClass('disabled');

});
```

```css
.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name-field" class="name-field row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 childname">
    <div class="field text-left">
      <label class="text-left">Name</label>
      <input class="firstname" name="firstname[]" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 dateofbirth">
    <div class="field text-left">
      <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label>
      <input type="text" class="date" name="date[]" placeholder="DD / MM / JJJJ" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="stepname" class="btn disabled">Next step</a>
```

Comment: It is also not working like i want. It removing the the disabled when only fill in name field not even looking at date field.

Comment: right, there were a couple of errors. Please have a look to the update.

Comment: Still have some mistakes i think, it seem syntax is not correct. when you checking if (date)

Comment: @Zain the code now it disables the next link if edit a valid input data.